# Inside compound / building cabling for fiber

Tags: networking, cabling, fiber

I have a cabling challenge: we live in a compound that has a cabling room [room] to where all telecom infrastructure (copper and fiber services) arrive. That [room] is ~300 metres to our home [home]. The cabling then arrives to a box [box] in our street (10 metres to home) and from there it comes [home]. Telco operators only undertake work until the [room].

Cabling from the [room] to the [box] is from 1990s phone infrastructure, copper. From the [box] to [home] it's cat6 but only 2 of the 8 is used like good old days as noone around here has any networking knowledge and assume all cables are like old phone lines.

The result is a 2/3mb internet speed at home. The saddest part is there also is fiber that arrives to the [room] but obviously it's kinda useless because of [room] to [box] part.

Apparently from [room] to all [box]es around the compound there are housing pipes so it's possible to replace cables relatively easily without digging. Obviously everyone has this problem so even though people don't understand what causes it they're willing to invest to upgrading.

Assuming everyone wants to use fiber going forward and with these constraints what would be the best practice for an upgrade to this system? It would be great if you could also mention if there are any hardware requirements for the [room] and the [box].

I am assuming this problem/solution would also be applicable to a building with old copper infrastructure so hope it can help other folks as well.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following case:

- difficult to replace [room]-[box] wiring
- only one "client" arriving at [room] (a single contract with a single ISP, like at a hotel for example)
- you are or represent that one client

I would say to install a DSL server box and distribute the network over the '90s cabling.

Your case seems different though, because if I understand correctly:

- the telco is happy to run several "client" accesses to the [room]
- replacing [room]-[box] cabling is a possibility
- maybe replacing [box]-[house] is also possible?
- you are only one of many potential clients

You have three options for cabling:

- run fiber [room]-[box]-[home]. Probably single-mode is best (depends on distance, and all homes should have the same for simplicity's sake).
- run fiber [room]-[box] and keep the [box-home] cat6. I would not recommend this because you'd need to convert the fiber to copper in the [box], which needs equipment and electricity which you probably do not have in your [box].
- run DSL-over-copper (if I understand correctly this is what you have already, but maybe you could get better quality).

Then you have different options for connectivity:

- run your own mini-ISP, terminating your telco fiber and redistributing the network. That needs competence, time, a lot of work, the confidence of all your "clients", and may be a legal problem. This is often done in hotels.
- ask the ISP to install their equipment in your [room]. This would probably be best if you're stuck with copper between [room] and [house], because that way you minimize the copper length.
- terminate the ISP portion in the [room] for each house, putting their access box (often still called "modem") in the [room], and running the network from the [room] to the [house] under the responsibility of each house. This is not ideal because to reboot your access box you need access to the [room].
- run the ISP access direct to the houses (if I understand correctly this is what you have already, with DSL over copper)

I would definitely contact a local company to get the cost of running single-mode fiber from each [home] to the [room], because that is what is most flexible and future-proof. If that is economically feasible, negotiate with the telco.

Answer (score 0):

Physically, "drop fiber" tends to be a good choice for applications like this - it's a fairly robust fiber cable that's designed to "act like" telephone cable and is relatively hard to kink or bend too sharply. It also tends to be comparatively inexpensive.

In any case you'll want an "outside plant" type fiber, since it's in conduit underground and exposed to moisture as a result. So long as it's not more than 50 feet inside the house or room, that's fine; and "indoor/outdoor" type cable can be used if there's more than 50 feet inside the buildings.

Do not use an indoor type fiber - it will eventually fail if used in an exterior application.

For the fiber itself, it somewhat depends on what you are interfacing to, but in general, at this time, Reduced Bend Radius Single-Mode ends to be the best choice.